# Dynamics 356 v9 - use executionContext.getFormContext() with HTML web resource

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365, dynamics-crm-365-v9

Any ideas how we can we use `executionContext.getFormContext()` with an HTML web resource? only method that seems to work is `parent.Xrm.Page` which is now deprecated.

Answer (score 5):

We are still using `parent.Xrm.Page` and `parent.Xrm.Utility`, since the replacement is [not yet announced](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/get-started/whats-new/customer-engagement/important-changes-coming?WT.mc_id=DX-MVP-5004422#some-client-apis-are-deprecated).

> You should plan to use the new client APIs mentioned in the **Replacement Client API** column instead of the deprecated ones. The deprecated client APIs will continue to be available and supported until they are officially removed from a future major release of Dynamics 365.

> **Deprecated Client API**:
> [parent.Xrm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309536.aspx#BKMK_ReferencingOtherWebResources)

> **Replacement Client API**:
> NA

> **Comments**:
> **Earlier**: An HTML web resource may interact with the **Xrm.Page** or **Xrm.Utility** objects within the form by using parent.Xrm.Page or parent.Xrm.Utility.
> **Now**: parent.Xrm.* will work if the HTML web resource is loaded in a form container. For other places, such as loading an HTML web resource as part of the SiteMap, parent.Xrm.* won’t work.

Update:

Latest MS documentation says:

> Although `Xrm.Page` is deprecated, `parent.Xrm.Page` will continue to work in case of HTML web resources embedded in forms as this is the only way to access the form context from the HTML web resource.